# No events passed to WPF adorner layer

Tags: wpf, adorner

I am trying to make a nice "drag and drop zone" in WPF that is displayed in the adorner layer when something is being dragged into the main application. The problem is that I do not get any events from my adorner, even though it according to documentation should receive all input events since it is in a higher z-order.

To debug my problem I created a really simple example where I have a user control with only a button in it. This user control is displayed in the adorner layer, but I cannot click the button. Why? What have I done wrong?

My adorner class is constructed like this:

```
    public ShellOverlayAdorner(UIElement element, AdornerLayer adornerLayer)
        :base(element)
    {
        _adornerLayer = adornerLayer;

        _overlayView = new AdornedElement();
        _overlayView.AllowDrop = true;
        _adornerLayer.Add(this);
     }
```

and is created in the main window by

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(MyTopGridWithButtonInIt);
        ShellOverlayAdorner shell = new ShellOverlayAdorner(MyTopGridWithButtonInIt, adornerLayer);

    }
```

I do not get any events at all from my control, i.e. no mouse clicks, mouse over, button clicks. I cannot even click the button in the adorner layer. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It's working fine for me... are you sure you didn't set IsHitTestVisible to false on your adorner ?

Comment: Hmmm.. Strange, because I get this for all test projects I create.

No, I have not set IsHitTestVisible to false. I have tested setting it to both true and false to get a change, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if you already tried that:
If you want the element added to react to events, I think that the element must be bound to the visual tree of the adorner.
The way to do it is to use a **VisualCollection**, intitialized to the adorner itself, or at least, this way it seems to be working:

```
    VisualCollection visualChildren;
    FrameworkElement @object;

    public CustomAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) :
        base(adornedElement)
    {
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);
        @object = new Button {Content = "prova"};
        visualChildren.Add(@object);
    }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return visualChildren[index];
    }
```

This way the events are correctly routed.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Following the advice from MSDN sorted it for me:

> Adorners receive input events just
>   like any other FrameworkElement.
>   Because an adorner always has a higher
>   z-order than the element it adorns,
>   the adorner receives input events
>   (such as Drop or MouseMove) that may
>   be intended for the underlying adorned
>   element. An adorner can listen for
>   certain input events and pass these on
>   to the underlying adorned element by
>   re-raising the event.
>
> To enable pass-through hit testing of
>   elements under an adorner, set the hit
>   test IsHitTestVisible property to
>   false on the adorner.

i.e In the adorner itself, make sure IsHitTestVisible = false