# Cannot access adorners on element that has no adorners

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, adorner

I try to make some drag&drop on WPF using MVVM

I found this link from Bea Stollnitz http://bea.stollnitz which propose a solution 
with a DragDropHelper here : https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/46-DragDropListBox

but when i try to customize it with some events generating components such as button or radioButton in datatemplate, i have this error on drag & drop

"Cannot access adorners on element that has no adorners."

on this line

this.adornerLayer.Update(this.AdornedElement);

you can reproduce it easily by downloading bea.stollnitz.com/files/46/DragDropListBox.zip

and replacing

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pictureTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Location}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

by

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pictureTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Location}" />
            <RadioButton />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

i.e. adding a radiobutton in the template

i already find some links but none of them explain a clear way to solve the issue.

[No events passed to WPF adorner layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943525/no-events-passed-to-wpf-adorner-layer)

that propose to add this code

VisualCollection visualChildren;
    FrameworkElement @object;

```
public CustomAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) :
    base(adornedElement)
{
    visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);
    @object = new Button {Content = "prova"};
    visualChildren.Add(@object);
}
protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
{
    return visualChildren[index];
}
```

but i'm sure where to add it and same thing for this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e6643abc-4457-44aa-a3ee-dd389c88bd86?prof=required

that propose

```
private bool IsItemDisconnected(object item)
{
  bool isDisconnected = false;

  var itemType = item.GetType();
  if (itemType.FullName.Equals("MS.Internal.NamedObject"))
  {
    isDisconnected = true;
  }

  return isDisconnected;
}
```

this last link talk about a .NET 4 issue but i also have the bug on 3.5

Comment: So nobody seems to be inspired by my question. I find another implementation of bea stollnitz solution. Using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop.aspx, i finally maked drag&drop with event generating template. this solution look more like a code behind solution rather than a real mvvm one (because we directly manage with drag over and drop events in the view model), but it works without bug and have another advantage, it's possible to order the dropped items.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem with I think the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post on here that I had found a solution to this. After reading [Drag drop error : Cannot access adorners on element that has no adorners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987587/drag-drop-error-cannot-access-adorners-on-element-that-has-no-adorners)

```
if (this.adornerLayer != null && this.contentPresenter.Content != null)
{
    this.adornerLayer.Update(this.AdornedElement);
}
```